# Mysql routine error

Tags: mysql

I've a mysql routine which do not work :

```
delimiter #;
create procedure ancien ()
BEGIN
    declare postname CHAR;
    declare ID INT;
    declare count INT;
    declare counter INT DEFAULT 0;  

    select count(*) INTO @count FROM network_2_posts;

    LOOP: 'posts'

    set counter = counter + 1;

    IF counter <= count THEN select post_name, ID INTO @postname, @ID FROM network_2_posts;
        UPDATE network_2_postmeta SET meta_value = @postname WHERE meta_key = 'wpcf-identifier' AND post_id = @ID;
    END IF;

    IF counter > count
    THEN
        LEAVE posts;    
    END IF;

    END LOOP posts;

END#
```

MySQL show an error at this line :

```
 IF counter <= count THEN select post_name, ID INTO @postname, @ID FROM network_2_posts;
```

after THEN keyword.

Any idea ?

Thx a lot

Frédéric

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Never mind, add an enter character between the if ... then statement and the select statement.

Comment: And as a side note, the `#;` is probably the worst delimiter you can choose. The `#` is used to comment. It probably works, but when it does, your delimiter is `#;`, not only `#`, so your final `END` will not be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

thx.

My error was the LOOP statement.

The correct one is

posts: LOOP

and not

LOOP: posts